# Activity start delayed (with WakeLock)

Tags: android, android-activity, wakelock, start-activity

I have asked similar question before, but then problems were fixed after adding WakeLock. Some time have passed and problem has came back.

Background - it is an alarm application, with alarm Activity being started from BroadcastReceiver (code below). Problem has started occuring randomly, there were no problems previously. Application has build in Logger that saves logs to database - all information about the bug I have come from log sent by user - error has never occured to me... Log:

```
880. 6/3 5:0:1 - == Logger initialized == from AlarmReceiver
881. 6/3 5:0:1 - sending START ALARM
882. 6/3 5:0:1 - WakeLock creating
883. 6/3 5:0:1 - WakeLock acquiring for 300000
884. 6/3 5:0:2 - START ALARM send
885. 6/3 5:0:2 - logger initialized again from StartAlarmReceiver
886. 6/3 5:0:2 - logger initialized again from Main
887. 6/3 5:0:3 - start initializeTask //from Main.onCreate
888. 6/3 5:0:3 - Main start
889. 6/3 5:0:4 - Main resume
890. 6/3 5:0:4 - Main pause
891. 6/3 5:0:4 - Main stop
... not relevant
894. 6/3 6:0:0 - logger initialized again from AlarmOnScreen create
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Logger.initialize(context, "AlarmReceiver");
    if (call_is_on) {
        postAgainIn5Sec();
    } else {
        Utils.log("sending START ALARM");
        CountedWakeLock.acquireLock(context); // acquired for 30000 millis
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(StartAlarmReceiver.ACTION_START_ALARM);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());

        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
        Utils.log("START ALARM send");
    }
}
```

StartAlarmReceiver:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Logger.initialize(context, "StartAlarmReceiver");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmOnScreen.class);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    i.putExtras(extras);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

AlarmOnScreen (with android:launchMode="singleTask")

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_on_screen);
        Logger.initialize(this, "AlarmOnScreen create");
    //...
```

CountedWakeLock:

```
 public synchronized static void acquireLock(Context context, long delay) {
    if (sWakeLock == null) {
        Utils.log("WakeLock creating");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        sWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "AlarmReceiver lock");
        sWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
        sLockCount = 0;
    }

    Utils.log("WakeLock acquiring for " + delay);
    sLockCount++;
    sWakeLock.acquire(delay);
}
```

TL;DR - it took about hour for an AlarmOnScreen Activity to call its onCreate method after startActivity was called.

Question - why did activity not start just after calling startActivity?
Also, can I prevent Main from launching when Alarm is started? I do some loading in thread started from onCreate method and it is pointless, when Main shouldn't even be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Next log has clarified that problems were caused by WakeLock not working properly - for details please go to [WakeLock with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612544/wakelock-with-partial-wake-lock-is-not-working)